# ¿como limpiar los campos de un formulario en jsf?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Hola tengo mi forulario en jsf con primefaces
lo que quiero saber es como limpiar los datos una vez que ya los llene y le di en boton submit
porque si vuelvo a entrar me pinta los datos que ya habia ingresado, no se si sea desde la vista o si tenga que crear un metodo y luego como lo mando a llamar en la vista?

[![Es este parte de mi formulario][1]][1]

```html
<p:fieldset legend="#{datospersonalesmsgs['datospersonales.title']}" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">
                <h:panelGrid columns="5" width="100%" > 
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3" width="100%">
                        <!--CURP-->
                        <h:outputText value="#{datospersonalesmsgs['datospersonales.curp.title']}:*" />
                        <p:inputText id="datospersonales_curp" value="#{DatosPersonalesComponent.datospersonales.curp}" required="true"  label="datospersonales_curp"
                                    readonly="readonly" maxlength="18"  onblur="javascript:this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3" width="100%">
                        <!--NOMBRES-->
                        <h:outputText value="#{datospersonalesmsgs['datospersonales.nombre.title']}:*" />
                        <p:inputText id="datospersonales_nombre" value="#{DatosPersonalesComponent.datospersonales.nombre}" required="true"  label="datospersonales_nombre" 
                                     readonly="readonly" onblur="javascript:this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3" width="100%">
                        <!--Primer Apelldo-->
                        <h:outputText value="#{datospersonalesmsgs['datospersonales.apellido.title']}:*" />
                        <p:inputText id="datospersonales_apellido" value="#{DatosPersonalesComponent.datospersonales.apellido}" required="true" label="datospersonales_apellido"
                                   readonly="readonly"  onblur="javascript:this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: te funcionó la respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que hacerlo del lado del backend, primero tienes que agregar un atributo `widgetVar` al tag `<p:fieldset>`, este lo vas a usar para actualizar el tag después de hacer la operación de submit:

```
<p:fieldset widgetVar="datosPersonalesFieldSet" legend="#{datospersonalesmsgs['datospersonales.title']}" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">
```

Tu botón submit debe ser algo así:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{datosPersonalesComponent.submitOperation()}" update="datosPersonalesFieldSet"/>
```

El atributo `action` debe llamar la función que quieres enviar cuando se haga el submit, y el parámetro `update` debe concordar con el parámetro `widgetVar` del tag que contiene los datos del formulario, en este caso `datosPersonalesFieldSet`.

Y en tu componente `DatosPersonalesComponent` debes creas un método que limpie tus campos y lo llamas desde el método que invocas al dar click en el botón en este caso desde el método submitOperation() :

```
public submitOperation(){
   //logica del método
   clearFields():
}

private void clearFields(){
    //limpiar campos necesarios del objeto datospersonales
}
```